# whether extjs4.1 application will support in iPad Browser and Android Tablet Browser

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

can anybody tell whether extjs4.1 application will support in iPad Browser and Android Tablet Browser eg(whether design and listener) if its support then why they will go with sencha for mobile channel?

Comment: Please clarify what you want here.

Comment: What is difference between extjs4.1 and sencha ?